# Sublime text Math preview opens console window on every change in math fields

Tags: preview, sublime-text, live-preview

I am using latex in `Sublime Text 3`. The package `Math Preview` is certainly smart, but it opens up a console window on top of sublime on every change and this steals focus in about 3s, and the math preview is unusable in this form (screenshot).
I have tried to uninstall all latex packages and the same thing occured, and also to unistall both mitkex and sublime, same thing occurs again .

I have the math preview settings:

```
"preview_math_mode": "selected",
"preview_math_scope": "text.tex.latex meta.environment.math",
"preview_math_latex_compile_program": "pdflatex",
```

Does someone know how to remove this and make it run in the background?
Any help is welcome, Thanks
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It seems that you have both `LaTeXTools` and `La​Te​X Equation Preview` installed. I would suggest to uninstall `La​Te​X Equation Preview` and only use the LaTeXTools preview. Please compare https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues/1436

Comment: Thank you this worked! Amazing. I didn't know preview was in `LaTeXTools` already, perhaps i naively expected it wasn't due to the existence of `Latex Equation Preview`

Comment: I think both were developed in parallel after popups and phantoms were added to the Sublime Text api. However the `LaTeXTools` version has more efforts for a smooth integration than `Latex Equation Preview` (extra threads, caching of already rendered images, auto detection and usage of ghostscript, which is shipped with most LaTeX distros, instead of imagemagick, ...)